Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n e^{\sin{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge?
I am trying to study the converge of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n e^{\sin{n}}}{\sqrt{n}}$$
But $e^{\sin{n}}$ is not monotone, and the Abel's test rule fails here. Can someone help me? Thank you!

What do you study it for, if I may ask?

By the Dirichlet test it suffices to show that the sums
$$\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n e^{\sin n}$$ are bounded. This is true - to see this, apply this answer to $f(x) = -e^{\sin(2x-1)} + e^{\sin(2x)}$ for example.
